# Java regex matching not working

Tags: java, regex, match

I'm trying to write a Search class that searches a list containing dataItems that have an id property, for hits against a list of such ids.

But I can't get the regex to work properly. I've tried printing the string variable containing my regex and then matching against that instead of the variable which makes it work for some odd reason.

I do it in this method:

```
private <D extends dataItem> boolean subSearch(D d){
    boolean b = false; 

    for(String sf: d.getSearchField(searchF)){  
        System.out.println(sf); //String of id I match against
        System.out.println(searchQ); //Prints "(A0A5E1)|(A4QPC6)|(A6NC42)|(A6NMB1)|(A6NI73)"
        System.out.println(sf.matches("(A0A5E1)|(A4QPC6)|(A6NC42)|(A6NMB1)|(A6NI73)"));//Prints true
        b = b || sf.matches(searchQ);  
        if(sf.matches(searchQ)){ //Does not match when sf.matches("(A0A5E1)|(A4QPC6)|(A6NC42)|(A6NMB1)|(A6NI73)") matches
            System.out.println(searchQ);
            System.out.println(sf);
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Any ideas of what is going wrong with sf.matches(searchQ)?

Comment: What is the value of sf?

Comment: if `sf.matches("(A0A5E1)|(A4QPC6)|(A6NC42)|(A6NMB1)|(A6NI73)")` is true and searchQ is `"(A0A5E1)|(A4QPC6)|(A6NC42)|(A6NMB1)|(A6NI73)"` then `sf.matches(searchQ)` must be true also.

Comment: An id string. Like 'A0A5E1', 'A4QPC6' or some other id not in my search list. I've checked and it does print these ids.

Comment: What is an example of the entire string you expected to match?

Comment: And `d.getSearchField` returns a `String[]`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issues. I even executed this locally(only the body inside for loop), and `if(sf.matches(searchQ))` is returning true for me.

I believe `searchQ` is not having the correct regex.

Comment: You are right. "searchQ" contained '\r' character which didn't show up when I printed the string.